# What does pointer to pointer do in this example?

Tags: c++, pointers

I got to know by searching on the Internet that pointer to pointers are referring to the pointers in which the address is stored. But I don't get this example with using them in the tables. Is it like that **tab makes it possible to look into *[rows] which is the value of each row?

Changing **tab into a simple tab causes program not to run.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void write_elements_of_the_table(int **T,int rows, int columns) {

    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
    cout <<"\t["<<i<<"]";
    }

    cout<<endl;

    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        cout <<"["<<i<<"]";
       for (int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        cout <<"\t  "<< T[i][j];
       }
    cout<<endl;
    }
}


int main()
{ 
    int **tab, columns,rows;
    cout<<"Write the amount of rows:"<<endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout<<"Write the amount of columns"<<endl;
    cin >> columns;
    // pointer table
    tab = new int *[rows];
    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
      tab[i]=new int[columns];
    }

    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
       for (int j=0;j<columns;j++){
        cout<<"Write the element value"<<endl;
        cin>>tab[i][j];
       }

    }

    write_elements_of_the_table(tab,rows,columns);

    //deleting the table

    for (int i=0;i<rows;i++){
        delete []tab[i];
    }

    delete []tab;

    return 0;
}
```

I would like to understand the meaning of the **T and **tab.

Comment: A pointer: that's the object over there -> .  A pointer to pointer: that thing over there can tell you where the object is, I'm just pointing to the other pointer.

Comment: A pointer is a variable that (if appropriately initialised) contains the address of another variable.   A pointer to a pointer is a variable that contains the address of a pointer.

Comment: As an aside: Only use `T` for the first type-argument of a template, all other uses are weird.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to understand the meaning of the **T and **tab.

`int` is a type. More specifically, it is an integer type.

`int*` is also a type. More specifically, it is a pointer type. Pointers point to other objects. An object of `int*` type in particular points to an object of type `int`.

`int**` is also a pointer type. It too points to other objects. An object of `int**` type points to an object of type `int*`. `int **T` and `int **tab` are variables of type `int**`.

---

`new[]` expression allocates an array of objects with dynamic storage. The value returned by the expression is a pointer to the first element of that array.

`new int[n]` allocates an array of `int` objects. The value returned by the expression is a pointer to the first objectt in that array. The type of that pointer is `int*`.

`new int*[m]` allocates an array of `int*` objects. The value returned by the expression is a pointer to the first object in that array. The type of that pointer is `int**`.

The concise description of `tab` is: `tab` is a pointer to the first element of an array of pointers where each element of the array points to the first element of an array of integers.

Comment: Imho, the interesting ones are `columns` and `rows`, specifically in `main()`.

Comment: This answer, while correct, would be *better* IMHO, if it showed how OP could simplify this by using containers and smart pointers.